# Combining multiple .tex files, *rendered as if they were compiled independently*

Tags: pdfpages, multiple-files, combine

I want a way to create a document that just concatenates the PDFs I would get from compiling multiple .tex files independently.

I can do this "manually" by compiling each file to produce a PDF independently, and then combining the results using pdfpages (see below), but I'd rather save myself the trouble.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{compiled_tex_file1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{compiled_tex_file2.pdf}
\end{document}
```

I've tried cargo-culting online examples using various combinations of `standalone`, `subfiles`, `input`, `import`, `include`, `combine`, but haven't managed to get any of them working.

Comment: Using pdf manipulations tools like  https://github.com/DavidFirth/pdfjam or https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/ seems a better approach here...

Comment: @capybaralet You may also have a look at the `combine` package.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this is more about manipulating PDFs than LaTeX-related. I normally use [`pdftk`](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) (it is called *pdftk-server* on the site, but it's basically a command-line version of the app) which is normally available in your distribution:

```
pdftk file1.pdf file2.pdf cat output file1+2.pdf
```

will merge the files.

If you have a full TeXLive install, you have already [`pdfjam`](https://github.com/DavidFirth/pdfjam), where you can do the same with

```
pdfjam file1.pdf file2.pdf -o file1+2.pdf
```

which basically is a wrapper around the `pdfpages` LaTeX package and can do almost everything the package can.

Both packages can select, shuffle, rotate, resize, add watermarks, and so on on the pages.

Comment: Thanks, that is useful, but it doesn't really answer the question.  I want to be able to do this 100% in latex (e.g. on Overleaf) without using command line tools.